# airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I've been attempting to set up Apache Airflow on my local machine using Docker Compose.

I followed the official Docker Compose guide provided in the Airflow documentation (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html).

Despite following the steps outlined in the documentation, I encounter an issue when running the command `'docker compose up airflow-init'` to create a user account. The process exits with code 1, and I receive the following error.

```
airflow-airflow-init-1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     from airflow import settings
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1129, in <module>
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     conf.validate()
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 224, in validate
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     self._validate_config_dependencies()
airflow-airflow-init-1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 267, in _validate_config_dependencies     
airflow-airflow-init-1       |     raise AirflowConfigException(f"error: cannot use sqlite with the {self.get('core', 'executor')}")
airflow-airflow-init-1       | **airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor**
```

I've attempted to start from scratch by deleting everything and following the setup process again. However, the same error persists.

Comment: Python 3.6 doesn’t supported for a while. AFAIK support python 3.6 dropped into the 2.3. So if you ran old version of airflow with the latest docker compose file it is expected that it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as explained in the error message you get:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor

You are using `CeleryExecutor` which does not work with Sqlite. If you'd like to use Sqlite you need to use `SequentialExecutor` quoting from the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/sequential.html):

> The SequentialExecutor is the default executor when you first install airflow. It is the only executor that can be used with sqlite since sqlite doesn’t support multiple connections.

If you would like to use CeleryExecutor you must set MySQL or PostgresSQL as backend database.